# display string without the <tags> in XML using ruby

Tags: ruby, xml

I have the following:

`api_response`

```
=> "<parse>Awesome!  It looks great to me!\n  \n\n    \n    \n\n    <SETPROFILE>\n      <KEY>funnels.intro_funnel.edit_ME\nTHOD</KEY>\n      <VALUE>done</VALUE>\n    </SETPROFILE>\n  \
n\n    \n    \n\n    \n        You alright if we add another method later?\n\n        XHIDE YES NO ADD METHOD XHIDE</parse>\n"
```

I want the string as follows:

```
"Awesome!  It looks great to me!  You alright if we add another method later?  XHIDE YES NO ADD METHOD XHIDE"
```

**How I got here:**

I extracted the original `api_response` and got the following array:

```
["Awesome!  It looks great to me!", "You alright if we add another method later?\n\n        XHIDE YES NO ADD METHOD XHIDE"]
```

But I couldn't figure out how to string it together.  I used .join(',') but now have an extra `,`.

**QUESTION:**

a) If I have this array, how can I make it a string as above?

b) Are there cleaner ways.  I used an XML extraction library but it outputs the non XML as the array above.

Comment: How about join with space instead of comma? .join(' ')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to join it by space, not comma:

```
a = ["Awesome!  It looks great to me!", "You alright if we add another method later?\n\n        XHIDE YES NO ADD METHOD XHIDE"]
a.join
#=> "Awesome!  It looks great to me! You alright if we add another method later?\n\n        XHIDE YES NO ADD METHOD XHIDE"
```

But here you see extra new lines and extra spaces. To remove it you could `split` and `join` again:

```
a.join.split.join(' ')
#=> "Awesome! It looks great to me! You alright if we add another method later? XHIDE YES NO ADD METHOD XHIDE"
```

Comment: This worked. I had to add a space rather than just 'join' because then there was no space. But other than that it seems find!